# Autocompletion using ajax and servlets

Tags: jquery, ajax, jsp, servlets

I am trying to create autocomplete by throwing an ajax request and json response from servlets. But dont no where am going wrong. Servlets is working fine. but request from ajax is not going. Please help me in this. 
Thanks in advance..

NewServlet.java

```
      Gson gson = new Gson();

      String prefix = request.getParameter("term");

      ArrayList<String> matchingSuggestions=   suggestions.getAllPrefixMatches(prefix);

         //final List<AutoCompleteData> result = new ArrayList<AutoCompleteData>();
      for (String suggestion : matchingSuggestions) {

            json = gson.toJson(suggestion);
            // result.add(new AutoCompleteData(suggestion,suggestion));

        }
          response.setContentType("application/json");
          response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        //  response.getWriter().write("<option>"+new Gson().toJson(result)+"<option>");      // Write response body.

           response.getWriter().write(json);
       }
```

autocomplete.html

```
 <html>
 <head>
  <script    src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="autocompleter.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
       </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="search-container">
           <div class="ui-widget">
            <input type="text" id="search" name="search" class="search" />
           </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

autocompleter.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
     $(function() {
             $("#search").autocomplete({     
             source : function(request, response) {
             $.ajax({
                     url : "NewServlet",
                     type : "GET",
                     data : {
                             term : request.term
                     },
                     dataType : "json",
                     success : function(data) {
                             response(data);
                     }
                });
             }
          });
      });
   });
```

Comment: try changing url to url : "NewServlet.Java" ?

Comment: Give the ajax call the `error:` function so you can see the error, or use the javascript console in your browser to debug.

Comment: @Johny Unless he mapped his servlet to that url in web.xml, that's not it.

Comment: debugged it in console its giving me error in script tag src=js/jquery.autocomplete.js  404 not found

Comment: @Veena Well, then you're sure your jquery.autocomplete.js file exists in that location specified?

Comment: yes its in js folder

Comment: @Veena please post your folder structure.

Comment: i could resolve error. i seperated autocompleter.js and html file n placed that in webINf. there are no more errors now.  but its not working. ajax call is not going. Is there something wrong in my code.